# Why is this Array.length if else check not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

[image]

Obviously `tagObjects` is an array and has a length of `0`. However it's still getting past that check and causes an error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

```
if (tagObjects != "empty" || tagObjects.length === 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tagObjects.tags.length; i++) {
        temp_tags.push(tagObjects[i].tags);
    }

    temp_tags.forEach(function(obj) {
        if (obj.selected) {
            if (vs.tags[map[obj.term]] != undefined) {
                vs.tags[map[obj.term]].selected = true;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It's even getting past the string check!

[image]

Comment: its the `tagObjects.tags.length` which is causing the issue, I believe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an OR condition

```
if (tagObjects != "empty" || tagObjects.length === 0) {
```

If it's not the string `"empty"` ***OR*** if it has no length, continue.

In other words the length doesn't matter if the Array **is not** the string `"empty"`, which it probably always is if it's an array ?

Also, you're accessing `tagObjects.tags` which suggest it's neither a string nor an array, but an object, and objects don't have length.

In other words, your `if` condition makes no sense at all ?

```
if (tagObjects != "empty" && tagObjects.length === 0) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You're making sure `tagObjects` exists, but it doesn't have a `tagObjects.tags` property (which you use on the second line). That's probably where the error is coming from.

You should change the initial condition to use something like:

```
if (tagObjects !== 'empty' && tagObjects.tags && tagObjects.tags.length > 0) {
```

This also changes the string comparison to be strict (`tagObjects` must be the exact string `empty` without coercion) and the condition from OR (any one must be true) to AND (all must be true).

The result is a condition that checks to make sure `tagObjects` is not the string 'empty' and has a defined property `tags` with a length greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks! `+1` Now I need to get past another problem hehe, tagsObjects[i].tags looks like I need another for loop to separate out tags.

Comment: @LeonGaban - You can't iterate over `tagObjects.tags` and then access `tagObjects[i]`, it just doesn't make any sense

Comment: Yeah, making another array to separate out the tags, then do this check. Thanks for helping with the 1st problem.